# how can I display that the user succesfully registered on my sign-in modal

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, dom, modal-dialog

this is my ajax script

```
if (result=='123') {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'ajax',
                    method: 'post',
                    url: url,
                    data: data,
                    async: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response){
                        if(response.success){
                            $('#signinForm')[0].reset();
                            if(response.type=='add'){
                                var type = 'added'
                            }else if(response.type=='update'){
                                var type ="updated"
                            }


                        } else {
                            alert('Error');
                        }
                    },
                });
            }//end of if(result == '123')
        });//end  of #btnSave
```

if the user pass the validation i want to display on the modal that they successfully registered and they can now login

Comment: why don't you `alert('Successfully registered')` in `if(response.success)`

Comment: Also if you dont want simple alert then use [bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com/) or similar plugin do display message